# Second min values with same count in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

My table like this

```
 A     B
7499   300
7521   400
7654   500
7698   0
7844   200
7900   0
```

I am trying like this

```
select deptno,count(1) ,min(comm)from emp
where deptno=30
group by deptno
```

I am getting output

```
count min(B)
6         0
```

But I need

```
  count min(B)
6         200
```

**with out using b >0 concept**

Comment: match your sample data field names with your query field names

Comment: So you're looking for the second lowest value?  What should be returned if there is only one value or no values for a deptno?

Comment: so many dept no is ther.

Comment: You can use some analytic functions magic or you can write your own aggregate function. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/aggr_functions.htm

Comment: Do you actually want the second lowest; or do you only want 200 because you want to exclude zeros?

Comment: Yes,second lowest,except zero

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CASE` like this to filter out `comm > 0`

```
select deptno,count(1) ,min(CASE WHEN comm > 0 THEN comm ELSE NULL END)
from emp
where deptno=30
group by deptno
```

Comment: sorry ,your query return 300.but i need 200

Comment: @Vinoth_S - it gets 200 with the sample data you had, if all of those were in department 30.

Comment: Just as Alex said, I am assuming all the data you provided is for department 30. can you provide what data you are using for your query? maybe a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your expecting the lowest that ISNT `0` then just add this into the where clause

```
SELECT deptno, count(*), MIN(comm)
FROM emp
WHERE deptno = 30
AND MIN(comm) != 0
GROUP BY deptno
```

Comment: @Matt - you need just `comm != 0`, not `MIN(comm)`; you can't use a group function in the where clause. Not sure if that will break the "with out using b >0 concept" restirction added as an edit.